# div is not at the bottom of the one bevor

Tags: html, css

im already finished with the site but i got a lil problem.

i would like to put three hover boxes on the top of the icon box and text as u can see on this pic.

[image]

the problem is that if i do a new div box its on top of the #webicons box .

would be nice if ya could !

Here is the actual status. http://www.awesom-media.de/umgebung/index.html

jsfiddle.net/D6V6R/

Comment: Where exactly do you want the red box `#referenzbox`, what is it for?

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution work's though I dont think your `li`s in the `#referenzbox` are the correct dimensions as currently they are too big for all to fit on one line.

Currently the container has a `width` of `1200px` and the three `li`s at `400px` plus `padding` are to wide for this.

If you `white-space: nowrap;` on `#referenzbox ul` you can see this issue.

Personally, I would close `#block-container` just before `#referenzbox` and set `width: 100%;` on this `#referenzbox`.

You can adjust the sizes to fit your needs.

```
#referenzbox {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

.webdesignbox {
    max-width: 520px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 545px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

In short, as you floated the icons, you needed to clear them on the next `div` with `clear: both;`